# Postgres Performance with Radius Searches

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance

Im porting an application from mysql to postgres, and have several tables with 500k+ rows in each of geo points (lat, lon). In mysql i used a bounding box query with haversine to select rows within a given distance of a center point. i understand i can use either postgis's st_dwithin or the earthdistance module (or i could probably port my mysql query over too). Just wondering if anyone has a recommendation on which method would be best performance wise with these large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Use st_dwithin. It will use the spatial index and do the job very fast if it is only points. 500 000 points is not that much.